# WPF window application size get changed also when NoResize and Maximised

Tags: wpf, user-interface

My application is a simple desktop UI in wpf , i want to run it always in maximized state so i provided ResizeMode=NoResize , still it's get shrink when user drags holding on title bar how can i prevent this
my xaml looks like this

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.MyScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI"        
    Title="MyScreen" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" WindowState="Maximized" 
            Closing="Window_Closing"  
            ResizeMode="NoResize" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp">
</Window>
```

any help will be appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just set `ResizeMode="NoResize"`, then the window can be resided by double click. I'm not sure if you can resize it by dragging mouse. dragging just moves the window.
anyway, You can set `WindowStyle="None"`.